# Converting a conditional constraint (if-then) to integer linear programming.

Tags: integer-programming, binary-programming

How can I linearly express the following conditional constraint:  If x1 = 1 (x1 is selected) then x2+x3 = 0 (x2 and x3 is not selected) if x1,x2 and x3 are binary?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting your logical proposition in conjunctive normal form somewhat automatically yields two linear constraints:
\begin{equation}
x_1 \implies (\neg x_2 \land \neg x_3) \\
\neg x_1 \lor (\neg x_2 \land \neg x_3) \\
(\neg x_1 \lor \neg x_2) \land (\neg x_1 \lor \neg x_3) \\
((1- x_1) + (1- x_2) \ge 1) \land ((1- x_1) + (1- x_3) \ge 1) \\
(x_1 + x_2 \le 1) \land (x_1 + x_3 \le 1)
\end{equation}
Another approach is to form a single big-M constraint:
$$x_2+x_3\le 2(1-x_1).$$ But that is weaker, being an aggregation of the previous two constraints.  For example, the big-M constraint does not cut off $x=(1/2,1/4,3/4)$.